# Getting random points from a multipolygon with the properties of the multipolygon

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to get random points from a multypoligon with saved properties, but i dont get properties , how to fix that?

`var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(main_crops,70)`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code. By looking at the documentation https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-randompoints this function does not copy the attributes.

Create first a new layer with random points and then join the attributes from the source layer with a spatial join https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/joins_spatial.